# uploading code to dev or production server using ftp or using telnet, are they both not safe?

Tags: ftp, ssh, sftp, telnet

i still see people using ftp or telnet for work instead of sftp and ssh.  is it true that using ftp or telnet can let people see the password quite easily?  Who can actually see it?

**Update:** for example, if i am not using Wireless... which i heard can be breakable if it is WEP when 1GB traffic is sent or received ... so if not using Wireless, and I am using either DSL, Cable Internet like Comcast, or AT&T's U-verse's fiber optics, then who can read it?  Can my neighbor, or joe at the data center at a nearby company or university read it?  Or joe at a big hosting company or data center that happens to be some where between California and Chicago if I am ftp'ing from California to Chicago?

**Update 2:** so maybe it is good to alias ftp='echo use sftp!!' on the bash too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer briefly, anyone on the path of the packets from your pc to the server.
In some cases (insecure networks, wireless networks, and so on) many more persons.
That's because the password will travel in plain text.

You can see more about packet sniffing at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_capture.
Also check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Security_problems

Answer (score 2):

Both ftp and telnet are unencrypted. That means that anyone who can capture your internet traffic (e.g. your isp, hosting provider, maybe government) can read your password in plain text averytime you login. Ssh and sftp/scp will encrypt your password and none should be able to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using a simple packet sniffer, such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) it is possible to read the plaintext passwords used by telnet and ftp.  Try using this tool while initializing a ftp or telnet session and you'll see how non-secure these mechanisms are.

As tagged with this post, ssh and sftp are more secure alternatives as they encrypt the data as it moves across the wire. And, as always, never use these sorts of tools for evil!

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with a sniffer can see it. Use the secure equivalents i.e. SFTP and SSH instead. They are protected with strong encryption and everything will be encrypted.